# Load Kendo Grid in Kendo Window

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-window

I want to open Kendo Grid in Kendo Window. My Kendo window code is like this.

```
   $("#Dialog").kendoWindow({
            title: "Add",                
            modal: true
        });

        var dialog = $("#Dialog").data("kendoWindow");          
        dialog.center().open();
```

I want to open kendo grid in window. I am not passing any values to the window.
When Opening the window, I want to read data from database and populate the grid. How can I do this ? Can I use Partial View for the Grid and Load in Kendo Window ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can load a partial view in a Kendo Window via a content url:

```
    $('#Dialog').kendoWindow({
        content: {
            url: "/AppName/ViewName" OR "ViewName/ControllerMethod"
        },
        title: "Add",                
        modal: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use iframe option

[See Demo](http://jsbin.com/nobevetulu/1/)

```
$("#window").kendoWindow({
                        width: "615px",
                        title: "Window",
                        iframe:true
                    });

function openWindow(_title, _url) {
                var manager = $('#window').data("kendoWindow");
                manager
                    .title(_title)
                    .center()
                    .open()
                    .refresh({
                        url: _url
                    });
                }
```

Replace google url with `@Url.Action("Action Name")`

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a partial view that contains your Grid
2. in javascript:
    make an ajax call to action that return this partiel View:

   ```
   var kWindow = $("#window").data("kendoWindow");
   $.ajax({
           url: YourController/OpenGridPartielView,
           cache: false,
           success: function (result) {
               kWindow.refresh
               {
                   $("#window").html(result);
               };
               kWindow.center().open();
           },
           error: function (result) {
           }
       });
   ```

   // in controller ..

   ```
   public PartialViewResult OpenGridPartielView()
   {   
      return PartialView(@"your PartielView Path");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an Empty Div where you can render your grid. Have the visibility hidden

   ```
   <div id="Dialog" style="display:none;">
   </div>
   ```
2. Create a Kendo Window and unhide the div whenever you want.

   ```
   document.getElementById("Dialog").style.display = "block";
   $("#Dialog").kendoWindow({
       visible: false,
       modal: true,
       actions: ["Minimize", "Close"],
       title: "Select an Enterprise",
       width: "400px",
       visible: false
   });
   var _dialog = $("#Dialog").data("kendoWindow");
   _dialog.center().open();
   ```
3. Make an Ajax call to the controller and render the output in the earlier mentioned Div

   ```
   $.ajax({
    url: RootUrl + 'Controller/ActionMethod',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json;',
    data: JSON.stringify({ Property: Value }),
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
       document.getElementById("Dialog").innerHTML = data;
   }
   });
   ```
4. In the Controller, return a partial View that would contain your grid

   ```
   public ActionResult ActionMethod()
   {
      return PartialView("PartialViewName");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I see some examples above using a PartialView, which is fine, but here is another way that does not use PartialViews.

I would create a div element for the window and another for the grid. I would then instantiate both kendo elements using a custom parameter for grid read event, so that results could be dynamic.

My javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
//VARIABLE TO HOLD PARAMETER VALUE FOR READ EVENT
    var id = 0;
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        var dialog = $("#kendoWindow").data("kendoWindow");
        dialog.center().open();
    });
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: 'YOUR URL TO CONTROLLER ACTION',
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: function() {
                        return {
                            id: id
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "ProductId",
                    fields: {
                        ProductName: { type: "string" }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 20
        },
        height: 550,
        columns: [
            "ProductId",
            "ProductName"
        ]
    });

    $("#kendoWindow").kendoWindow({
        title: "Add",
        model: true,
        open: function () {
        //ON OPEN EVENT OF WINDOW YOU CAN CHANGE THE PARAMETER IF NEEDED
            id = 10;
            $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
        }
    });
});
```

My Html:

```
<h2>kendoGridinKendoWindow</h2>
<button id="btn">Open Window</button>
<div id="kendoWindow">
    <div id="grid"></div>
</div>
```

My Controller Action (change as needed):

```
public JsonResult GetData(int id)
{
    if(id == 0) {
        List<Product> data = new List<Product>();
        for(var i=0; i< 10; i++){
            data.Add(new Product{ ProductId = i, ProductName ="test" + i});
        }
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        List<Product> data = new List<Product>();
        data.Add(new Product { ProductId = 0, ProductName = "test" });
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```